# Function generator output

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, function-generator

[image]

A function generator is hooked up to two resistors in series.

The voltage across the function generator changes over time, shown by the different graphs

The questions asks to find the output voltage at points w,x,y,z with respect to the ground.

I have a few points of confusion: how does the current behave? If d is grounded, doesn't current just leave the loop? What does the voltage output actually mean?

I know only have a very basic understanding of circuits: Ohms Laws and Kirchhoff laws so this question is giving me some trouble.

Comment: It's a trick question because **w,x,y,z** are **not at the same time** on each waveform. Then it shows the trace for **a** but doesn't ask to report the result for w,x,y,z in each trace for **a or b**. So it is a double whammy.  Just eyeball each reading as for each trace as peak or peak /2 or 3/4,  then if converting **a to b**  apply the R ratio divider ratio. and make a table of results or print over the traces. GND only means 0V ref and does not imply any current unless there are multiple gnd symbols

Comment: How would the circuit behave differently when the current is negative?

Comment: what's your guess with gnd=0V?

Comment: Also, this question is a theory.   In practice, all lab instruments are 50 Ohms Generators and for video 75 Ohms and for the AC grid and audio Amps = milliohms

Comment: I'm wondering if d being grounded would be an issue if the direction of the current was reversed

Comment: remember gnd is just a floating reference so no current unless you have a loop somewhere ( with more thn 1 gnd then it is a logical jumper or a common bus) and neg. current means neg voltage, whereas "earth-gnd" is bonded to another reference "mother earth" :)  So what is (ii) x voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does the current behave?

It flows in a loop from a to b to c to d back to a.

> If d is grounded, doesn't current just leave the loop?

By Kirchhoff's Current Law, for every current flowing in to ground (assuming the ground symbol means a connection to some large conductive body) there needs to be another current flowing out of ground. But since there's only one connection from your circuit to ground, there can't be any return flow, and therefore the current flowing into ground is zero.

Really, the ground symbol here doesn't represent a connection to something outside the circuit. It just tells you what node will be used as a reference to define the voltage at the other nodes.

> What does the voltage output actually mean?

That needs to be provided as part of the problem definition.

It could be the voltage at `a` or `b` or `c` or `d`.

Only one of those choices will make the problem interesting, but in general, a circuit problem statement should make clear what terminal is considered the output of that circuit.

Comment: So if I want to find the voltage at point d. For the first example (i) and at t=w, would the voltage =0 since it all the energy is lost due to the resistors

Comment: Loop law: IRtotal - IR1- IR2 = 0 ?

Comment: @Doldrums, the voltage at `d` is 0 by definition since it's connected to the reference (ground) symbol.

Comment: Ok, so then what is the question asking for?

Comment: What does it mean by voltage with respect to the ground?

Comment: @Doldrums, the question isn't clear. My best guess is when they say "the output" they mean node `b`. But really they should state that clearly to make the question clear.

Comment: "Voltage with respect to ground" means the potential difference between some node and the designated ground node, measured in volts.

Comment: If the voltage across the function generator is 4 volts, then moving from point a to b you would lose 1/2 the total voltage and have 2 volts remaining. Does that sound right?

Comment: I'm using this property: Voltage applied to a series circuit is equal to the sum of the individual voltage drops. Does the change in voltage over time lead to any unique behaviors?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct. No, there's nothing tricky about this problem (unless there's something you haven't shared).